# How to use regex match to find a string in an array of patterns?

Tags: perl

Let's say I have an array of strings, e.g. `@matches = ("cat", "zebra", "apple")`, and I want to open a file and try to match these strings in the simplest way possible.

```
while (<MYFILE>)
{
    chomp;

    if (..some match condition...)
    {
        ..stuff..
    }
}
```

I could just use a `foreach` on each line to try to match, but I know there's got to be a concise way in Perl to say "if string X matches any of the patterns in array Y." I just can't seem to find this anywhere.

EDIT:

To clarify, here's the highly inefficient code:

```
while (<MYFILE>)
{
    chomp;

    foreach $m (@matches)
    { 
        if (~ /$m/)
        {
            ..stuff..
        }
    }
}
```

I know there's some shorthand method of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean with “matches”? (a) “is equal to”, (b) “contains as substring”, or (c) “matches when used as regex”? Are you willing to use non-core modules? This makes a fine use-case for the `any`-junction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `join` to make an impromptu regex?

```
my @matches = ("cat", "zebra", "apple");
my $rx = join "|", @matches;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ /$rx/) {
         # stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine but, first, I think it would be more efficient to compile the regex only once, either with `qr` or adding the `o` flag. And second, there is to pay attention to the ordering of the words in the alternation, because `cat|category` could be dangerous.

Comment: @Birei You foresee some trouble with strings where `cat` and `category` will conflict?

Comment: I thought that the OP wanted to know also what matched and not only if it exists a match. No problem, forget it.

Comment: @Birei Then you could do `my @words = /($rx)/g`, and order will not matter.

Comment: Umm... but in that case, in an array of words that have same prefix, longer words that are latter in the alternation branch they would never match. In the previous example always will match `cat` and never `category`. Wouldn't be safer something like `my $rx = join "|", reverse sort @matches`?

Comment: @Birei Oh, right. Yes, I suppose that would be the better way. Although the proper way perhaps would be to not allow `cat` to partially match `category`, using for example word boundary.

Comment: Yes. Word boundaries are a good option and probably faster. I had used also this kind of solution before but had never realized of that issue. I will take into account for future solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to use the entries of `@matches` as regexes. Then, you can join them to a larger regex:

```
my $rx = join '|', @matches;

while (<>) {
  do stuff if $_ =~ $rx;
}
```

If you want to match the literal contents of the entries of `@matches`, so that `@matches = ("foo+")` matches the line `foo+` and not `fooo` as above solution would do, you can construct the regex like

```
my $rx = join '|', map quotemeta, @matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @matches = qw( cat zebra apple );

{   local $" = '|';

    while (<>) {
        chomp;
        if (/@matches/) { ... }
    }
}
```

But be careful. Read the doc:

```
perldoc perlvar | grep "\$LIST_SEPARATOR" -A 12
```

:)